# Rails / Active Record has_and_belongs_to_many association - fetching a record

Tags: mysql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models User and Company associated by has_and_belongs_to_many.
I can fetch all users belonging to a certain company using

```
Company.find(id).users
```

The problem I've is finding all users that DO NOT belong to a certain company. Well, I could do that using

```
User.all - Company.find(id).users
```

But, I feel there's certainly a better way to achieve this. Is there an activerecord solution to this ?

Currently, I have 8 users (id from 1 to 8). When I try,

```
User.joins(:companies).where('companies.id = ?', 13).map(&:id)
```

I get result [7, 8] which is as expected. When I place != in the above query, the results are not what I want, i.e. array of 1 to 6.

Need help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way might be with a class method... something like:

```
class User

  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies

  class << self

    def exclude_company(company)
      User.scoped.reject! {|u| u.companies.include? company}
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your code:

```
@company = Company.find(company_id)
@users = User.exclude_company(@company)
```

YMMV; I've done similar things in the past, but the above code is untested.

Also, if this is a common query pattern, you would probably be better served by the extensions to ARel provided in [MetaWhere](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) and its companion MetaSearch. N.B. These are replaced by new gems by the same author in Rails 3.1

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and sorry for the late response. But this fires a query for each user, i.e. in my case a total of 8 queries. I guess I should be concerned about the number of queries being fired. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Yeah, I hit that n+1 queries wtf pretty hard with that suggestion... I edited, try the new version... should more efficient.